# Wordpress custom template changes not working/showing up

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress site using a custom made theme by some other developer. That theme uses several custom made templates. Each templates exposes some fields in the front page editor (Pages->Add New, Template).

Now I want to change some existing template, I edit the template file and updated/saved that. When I preview that page, I can see the changes but when I open that page in (front end) editor mode, I cannot see any changes.

For trial I deleted everything from that template and create a new page with that template selected and to my surprise I can see all the fields in the front end editor that were there before I deleted the template code.

To summarize, a custom template file had some field before, later on I deleted all the code but in front end editor I can still see those custom fields.

I tried some caching plugins and tried to clear cache but no help.

I am out of ideas that what this could cause this.

I cannot share code as my company do not allow that. So any clue/ideas will be helpful.

Thanks in advance...